# Flutter Padding and Margin Issues

Tags: android, flutter, dart, padding, margin

When generating a release build for my Flutter app, I'm encountering an unusual issue where padding and margins are inexplicably removed on certain devices. This problem is unique and doesn't occur during debug runs, where everything works as expected.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and what could be a possible solution or workaround for this peculiar behavior?

My Flutter Version:  3.13.9

I am adding a sample screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code lines so anyone can check and identify the issue ?

Comment: Also what are the devices which give the problem?

Comment: I've identified the issue — it seems to be related to the declaration of some default size constants in a separate file, which are then utilized throughout the app. 

https://gist.github.com/nahidnsu152/0d169746f6491049a63d4f3ae3b4a7f8